# Whacky multicol pagination in the (md)framed environment(s)

Tags: multicol, framed

This is a typical recommendation letter (minimally formatted) that includes questions and `\mdframed` responses in a `\multicol` environment. I have also included other things I typically include inside and outside of the `\multicol` environment. Using `\lipsum` paragraphs for example responses, this illustrates whacky column / pagination (especially a completely blank column on p2).

I also tried this with the `\framed` environment, with similar results.

Is there some hint or something that will allow framed paragraphs to stack up with minimal spacing and fully fill the columns?

All I really want to do is put frames around my response paragraphs, but have them behave like normal paragraphs in the `\multicol` environment.

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}%
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol,paracol,tabularx}
\usepackage[linewidth=1pt]{mdframed}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% to address
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{lr}
Alice Q. Public \\
1234 Main Street \\
Anytown NY 12345 USA
\end{tabular*}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% letter body
\begin{multicols}{2}
This is a typical recommendation letter (minimally formatted) that includes questions and \texttt{\textbackslash mdframed} responses in a \texttt{\textbackslash multicol} environment. I have also included other things I typically include inside and outside of the \texttt{\textbackslash multicol} environment. Using \texttt{\textbackslash lipsum} paragraphs for example responses, this illustrates whacky column / pagination (especially a completely blank column on p2). 

Is there some hint or something that will allow framed paragraphs to stack up with minimal spacing and fully fill the columns?

All I really want to do is put frames around my response paragraphs, but have them behave like normal paragraphs in the \texttt{\textbackslash multicol} environment.

{\em Table 1:}\vfill\null
\begin{tabularx}\columnwidth{|X|X}\cline{1-1}
Student's Name: & Bob Q. Public \\\cline{1-1}
Your Name: & Carol Q. Public \\\cline{1-1}
Your Email: & \texttt{carol@q.public} \\\cline{1-1}
Your title: & \LaTeX\ hacker \\\cline{1-1}
\end{tabularx}
\vfill\null

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
{\em Question 1:}
\begin{mdframed}
 \lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
{\em Question 2:}
\begin{mdframed}
 \lipsum[2]
\end{mdframed}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
{\em Question 3:}
\begin{mdframed}
 \lipsum[3]
\end{mdframed}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
{\em Question 4:}
\begin{mdframed}
 \lipsum[4]
\end{mdframed}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Thank you very much.
\end{multicols}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% closing
\begin{paracol}{2}\switchcolumn
Sincerely,

\vspace{18pt}

 Blah, blah, blah...
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably try using breakable tcolorboxes?

Comment: I ended up using [`tcolorbox`](https://texdoc.org/serve/tcolorbox.pdf/0). Thanks.